# Regex to match "www" or nothing

Tags: regex

I have the following URLs:

```
www.localhost.com
localhost.com
test.localhost.com
```

How would I match "www" or nothing in a Regex?

Comment: Do you just want to test if the URL starts with www?

Comment: Wouldn't it be a true statement that *any* string either (1) starts with www, or (2) does not start with www?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

```
(?:www)?
```

should match www or nothing.

Comment: What does the "?:" before "www" do?

Comment: `(abc)` is capturing, `(?:abc)` is grouping without capturing. See http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html

Comment: One thing to note though, is it still will not match localhost.com, you'll need to ignore the dot afterwards also.

Comment: This will match www anywhere in the string, such as examplewww.com

Comment: had to rewrite mine to include the `.` since the non-www doesn't have a leading dot anywhere: `^(?:www\.)?`

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you need to use a lookahead, like this:

```
/^www(?=\.localhost.com)/
```

This will match `www` if and only if it's followed by `.localhost.com`.

If that's not what you're trying to do, please clarify.

Comment: This won’t match anything because you can’t match a `.localhost.com` after the end of the string.

Answer (score 0):

`/^www/` alows you to check if subjects starts with `www`.

Answer (score -2):

www.+?
It matches all string that has prefix as www