# Python regex match url without file extension

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to make a regular expression that will match a relative url that doesn't end with a file extension. Omitting urls with directories for simplicity, I expect the following:

| Url to match | Expected result |
| --- | --- |
| /foo | match |
| /foo. | match |
| /foo.bar | no match |

I'm currently trying the regex `'(/[a-zA-Z]+)*/([a-zA-Z]+)(?!\.[a-zA-z]+).*?'`. This matches "/foo" and "/foo." as expected. However, it also matches "/foo.bar". `regex.match('/foo.bar')` returns `<re.Match object; span=(0, 3), match='/fo'>`. It seems that the negative lookahead, instead of not matching if a string ends in a file extension, takes a character from what should be the preceding group.

How do I accomplish what I'm trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding `$` and `(?:\.)?`:

```
>>> re.match('(/[a-zA-Z]+)*/([a-zA-Z]+)(?!\.[a-zA-z]+)(?:\.)?$', '/foo.bar') # No match
>>> re.match('(/[a-zA-Z]+)*/([a-zA-Z]+)(?!\.[a-zA-z]+)(?:\.)?$', '/foo.')
<re.Match object; span=(0, 5), match='/foo.'>
>>>
```

Comment: That works. If you don't mind me asking, what does (?:) mean? I know (?=) is positive lookahead and (?!) is negative lookahead, but I've never seen that before.

Comment: @AnthonyBias Ah, `(?:)` means match something or nothing, check here for more: [Regex to match "www" or nothing](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2038030)

Comment: @U12-Forward `(?:)` does not mean "match something or nothing".  (That's what the trailing `?` does after the closing `)`). `(?:)` is a _non-capturing_ group, as opposed to just a parenthesised subpattern that is a _capturing_ group. But in this example the _group_ is superfluous anyway, since it contains just a single character. `(?:\.)?` is the same as `\.?`.

Answer (score 0):

If your only goal is to map the URL to a pattern, you can use `fullmatch()` without lookahead and capture groups:

```
import re

for txt in ['/foo', '/foo.', '/foo.bar']:
    r = re.fullmatch('(?:/[a-zA-Z]+)*/[a-zA-Z]+\.?', txt)
    print(txt,'match' if r else 'no match')
```

Prints:

```
/foo match
/foo. match
/foo.bar no match
```